# The $n^\text{th}$ term in the sequence $\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{1},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{2},\frac{3}{1},\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{3},\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions

$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline R\text{ \ }C & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots \\ \hline 1 & \frac{1}{1} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} &  \\ \hline 2 & \frac{2}{1} & \frac{2}{2} & \frac{2}{3} &  \\ \hline 3 & \frac{3}{1} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{3} &  \\ \hline \vdots &  &  &  & \ddots \\ \hline  \end{array}$

Considering the sequence of fractions that is made by moving diagonally, with respect to the entries above, in the following manner:

$$\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{1},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{2},\frac{3}{1},\dots$$

where the entries are obtained by dividing the value of the row $R$ by the value of the column $C$.

So the next few terms are $\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{1},\frac{1}{5},\dots$

Now I have two question:

---

> What is the $n^\text{th}$ term in the sequence (including all
>   fractions)?

---

> What is the $n^\text{th}$ term in the sequence (excluding repeated
>   values)?

For example, $\frac{4}{2}$ has to be excluded since $\frac{2}{1}$ is already considered. Similarly, $\frac{2}{2},\frac{3}{3},\frac{4}{4},\dots$ are to be excluded since $\frac{1}{1}$ is already there.

---

What I observed is; for any natural number $m$, the $(2m^2+2m+1)^\text{th}$
term is to be excluded since that term is equal to $1$ which is already considered.

Also, it is easy to find an expression in $m$ to exclude other fractions

I have no idea to solve these two questions.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Note that the numerators are $(1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), \dots$ ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002260)) and the denominators are $(1), (2, 1), (3, 2, 1), (4, 3, 2, 1), \dots$ ([OEIS](https://oeis.org/A004736))

Comment: The first (easy) part of the question is numbering the fractions (Peter Foreman has already given the essential hint in his comment). The second (tough) part deals with divisibility in order to exclude double counting.

Comment: +1 Interesting question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**§ 1 Frame of reference**

It is useful to adopt a two index identification of the fractions.

Decompose the fractions into groups according to a scheme of numerators and denominators as shown for the first 4 groups below

$$(1)(1 2)(1 2 3)(1 2 3 4)...$$
$$(1)(2 1)(3 2 1)(4 3 2 1)...$$

The position $p_s(k)$ of the start of the k-th group in a linear sequence of fractions is given by

$$p_s=1+\frac{1}{2} k(k-1), k=1, 2, …\tag{1}$$

which is the sequence $1, 2,4,7,11,16,...$.

We can write the fractions in group $k$ as

$$f(k,m) = \frac{m}{k-m+1}, m=1..k\tag{2}$$

The position of fraction $f(k,m)$ in the sequence of all fractions is given by

$$p(k,m) = p_s+m-1=m+\frac{1}{2} k(k-1) \tag{3}$$

This can be inverted by

$$k(p)=\lfloor \left( \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2p-2} \right) \rfloor \tag{4a}$$

$$m(p) =p-\frac{k(p)}{2}(k(p)-1)\tag{4b}$$

Here $\lfloor . \rfloor$ is the floor function.

**§ 2 Drop repeated fractions**

If we wish to avoid double counting we have to check if the fraction is reducible. In other words we have to drop fractions with $GCD(m, k-m+1)\gt 1$.

I don't know how to express this condition in an explicit formula. Maybe others can.

Here is a related result:

Let $r(n)$ be the number of different rationals in our set of groups of fractions up to the element with the fraction $\frac{n}{1}$

Then $r(n)$ can be found by direct calculation to start like this

$$r(n) = {1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 17, 21, 27, 31, 41, 45, 57, 63, 71, 79, 95, 101}$$

This sequence is easily found in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A015614. And the formula is

$$r(n) =  -1 + \sum_{i=1..n} \phi(i)\tag{5}$$

where $\phi(i)$ is Euler's totient function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

The asymptotic behaviour is

$$r(n\to \infty) \simeq \frac{3}{\pi^2}n^2+O(n \log(n))$$

Since the number of primarily different fractions is $1+2+3+...+n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ the percentage of different fractions is given asymptotically by $\frac{6}{\pi^2} \simeq 0.607927$.

Comment: +1 already for your work, I am trying to understand by my self first, will be marked as useful answer soon when I finish, THANKS dear :)